# Why nan values appear on plotly heatmap?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have the following script

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

X = [0.001872507, 0.001873447, 0.001874379, 0.001875308, 0.001876231, 0.001877156, 0.001878074, 0.001878988, 0.001879891, 0.00188079]
Y = [15.87916667, 15.8375, 15.90277778, 15.92638889, 16.0875, 16.05833333, 16.11527778, 16.04166667, 16.1125, 16.09583333]
error = [-0.442834483, -0.404160852, -0.361559069, -0.319924963, -0.27351035, -0.222068364, -0.16524067, -0.194427625, -0.173130923, -0.13978894]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
        x=X,
        y=Y,
        z=error,
        colorscale='Viridis'))

fig.update_layout(
    title='Heatmap',
    xaxis_title='X',
    yaxis_title='Y'
)

fig.show()
```

As a result I have

[image]

You can see that when I hover over some point there is text "X:0.001873447 y: 16.04167,x:NaN"
Why does this appear? Can this be avioded?

Comment: because in the region you are hovering the mouse, the z value is not defined. it's only defined in the painted regions. What value do you expect z to be in that region?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this behaviour via the `hoverongaps` argument (see [this discussion](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/4291)):

```py
fig = go.Figure(
    data=go.Heatmap(x=X, y=Y, z=error, colorscale="Viridis", hoverongaps=False)
)
```